# Display age in select

Tags: ember.js

I'm new with ember. I try to display a simple select box that contains age value.
This is my controler :

```
App.HomeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
ages : function() {
    var ages = [];
    for(var i = 18; i <= 99; i++) {
        ages.push(i);
    }
    return ages;
}
});
```

This is my view :

```
<div class="container" id="main">
<div class="row">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Name : </label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                {{input type="text" name="name" value=firstname autofocus="true"}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="age" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Age : </label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                {{view "select" content=ages}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

i get this error when i refresh browser :

```
Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed function () {

var ages = [];

    for(var i = 18; i <= 99; i++) {

        ages.push(i);

    }

    return ages;

}
```

Anyone can tell me how i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ages` function resolved by handlebars. If you want to use it as a property add this to your function so you can use it in handlebars and also I would recommend you to use `Ember.A()` instead of javascript array.

```
ages : function() {
    var ages = Ember.A();
    for(var i = 18; i <= 99; i++) {
        ages.pushObject(i);
    }
    return ages;
}.property()
```

Not tested code by the way